# Too many markers makes chart unreadable. How to reduce number of markers?

Tags: reporting-services

I am charting a dataset that contains hundreds of datapoints as we're logging information about every 15 minutes and I want to report over a month's worth of data. When charting a single day's worth of data the readability is fine. But when I plot a month's worth of data, it is no long really readable due to me enabling markers. I have markers enabled as a requirement is to have it readable when printed in black & white.

What's the best practice to make the chart readable? Aggregating the data per hour/ per day is not an option as these are gauge readings and the customer doesn't want to lose any fidelity in the readings.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a long time ago, and I'm not 100% sure what your interval will be. Still this worked for me, and hopefully it will help someone else.

I needed to have the markers show up for every-other data point, so I used this expression for the name of the Marker Type:

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "Diamond", "None")
```

This is based on the commonly used code for alternating rows, but I think you should be able to modify the concept to get to what you need.

Comment: I reworked your code to True, False and used it to set the data labels only showing up every other data point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to set a max duration you want to view and test what that will look like for your users.  You can do a few things but all involve the 'tick marks' and labels for the most part.  On a chart object you can click once on a child element of the chart and select it.  You may do this for the vertical or horizontal axis of a standard line chart in my example.  Let's say you click on the vertical axis near the labels.  It will show a dotted rectangle to show it is selected.  Right Click and choose 'Vertical Access Properties'.

Select 'Major Tick Marks' on the left pane.

1. Your first option may be to 'Hide Major tick marks' select that and then do not see anything but labels.
2. Your second may be that you change the 'Interval' from AUTO to something else.  Change the 'Interval type:' to something else and then change the Interval as needed.
3. Maybe you need dynamic control, you can then select the 'fx' expressions to choose a type potentially that changes.  EG: Say you have a date range and someone selects month, maybe you want to make it weeks then, someone selects a year you want months, etc...

What you are describing is hard when you give a person a lot of data, you can also set just the beginning and end and then the line will adjust as necessary.  The key in good charting is to allow a user to see what they need but make it readable no matter what.  When you have broad options I find that less labels and ticks are best.

Comment: Not sure if my explanation was clear enough. I have a marker defined for each of my lines. Diamond is one of them, it seems that SSRS places a diamond on the line for every data point. I don't need so many diamonds, just a few would suffice. It's purely for viewing when printed in B&W.